# sqlserver joining on columns that were encrypted by passphrase

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, passphrase

I have a requirement to encrypt several columns using encrypt by passphrase method. unfortunately these encrypted columns need to be used in joins to one another.  and there are many views stored procs etc that I don't want to have to modify.

here is a fiddle of what is beneath if you would like to try it
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cc71b4969526eb0fedd22de2828abaa3

setup

```
create table encrypt.empsone(empno varchar(10),empno_encrypted varbinary(100));
create table encrypt.empstwo(empno varchar(10),empno_encrypted varbinary(100));

insert into encrypt.empsone(empno, empno_encrypted )
       values('001', EncryptByPassPhrase('my passphrase','001'))

insert into encrypt.empstwo(empno, empno_encrypted )
       values('001', EncryptByPassPhrase('my passphrase','001'))
```

everything looks ok

```
select a.empno,
      CONVERT(varchar,(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('my passphrase', a.empno_encrypted))) from encrypt.empsone a

empno      no name
  001        001
```

but the join does not work

```
select * from encrypt.empsone a join encrypt.empstwo b
on a.empno_encrypted = b.empno_encrypted
```

I am assuming because the encrypted values are not identical is there an option in encrypt by passcode to achieve this?  I am hopeful I do not need to rewrite all of the joins to use the decryptbypassphrase function

Comment: Why would you need to encrypt the keys?  They should be completely meaningless out of context.

Comment: they are foreign keys not primary keys. and yes they are completely meaningless but I was told they need to be encrypted. no idea why

Comment: Foreign keys in one table are primary keys (or their part) in some other tables.

Comment: ok sorry they are just columns that I need to do joins on

Comment: You want to change one static value for another.  Why would it be any safer if `001` becomes `998`?

Comment: The encryption is case sensitive. Meaning that key, Key and KEY will produce three distinct encrypted values. My guess is that is what is happening here. But something seems tragically flawed with the design if you need to join tables on values that need to be encrypted.

Comment: again I've argued the logic of this decision to no avail. this is my requirement

Comment: I understand it is your requirement. But my point about case sensitivity is almost certainly the issue here. I would push back at least a little bit and either fix the design or don't encrypt data that doesn't need to be.

Comment: so what they would like encrypted is basically an employee id like 00034587 so to my thinking  out of context it  is  totally meaningless. I will once again try to persuade the security team this is not necessary but...

Comment: OK something that is all numbers should encrypt to the same value. But also the datatype can come into play here. Are you 100% certain the datatype is exactly the same in every table? Is it possible that in some tables it was treated as an int before being encrypted? That would mean the two input values are different. There are just so many possibilities here.

Comment: If this is an audit requirement, you might as well go with SQL Server's Always Encrypted feature, but you'll need 2016.

Comment: @alans thanks for the Always Encrypted feature, that looks like the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear I just realized you are using EncryptByPassPhrase. Every time it runs it generates a new symmetric key. As such the output cipher will be different everytime you run this.

Take a look.

```
select EncryptByPassPhrase('my passphrase','001')
    ,  EncryptByPassPhrase('my passphrase','001')
```

To accomplish what you are trying to do requires you to decrypt the value which will give you the binary of the value you started with.

```
select * 
    , decryptbypassphrase('my passphrase', a.empno_encrypted)
    , decryptbypassphrase('my passphrase', b.empno_encrypted)
from empsone a 
join empstwo b on decryptbypassphrase('my passphrase', a.empno_encrypted) = decryptbypassphrase('my passphrase', b.empno_encrypted)
```

And if you need to get the original value back you simply cast the result of decryptbypassphrase to the original datatype.

```
select * 
    , convert(varchar(10), decryptbypassphrase('my passphrase', a.empno_encrypted))
    , convert(varchar(10), decryptbypassphrase('my passphrase', b.empno_encrypted))
from empsone a 
join empstwo b on decryptbypassphrase('my passphrase', a.empno_encrypted) = decryptbypassphrase('my passphrase', b.empno_encrypted)
```

Comment: Yeah trying to avoid that so i dont have to change all of the views stored procs

Comment: Given the nature of your current encryption you are stuck.

Comment: yeah I think I am going to try the always encrypted feature, seems to be working well. I used deterministic encryption so the views stored procs still work. and the .net entity framework supports it so the web application can still display and manipulate the data